# How to design a data structure which is a mixture of hashtable and heap

Tags: algorithm, heap, hashtable

My question is as following:

Given a list of triple, and they are stored in a data structure called hash_heap(I am not sure about the name,just mean it should be the mixture of the hashtable and heap). And I hope the data structure provides following methods,

```
index_by_first_col(key) // the method could help find the a triple stored in it by matching the first column. It expects the searching is running at constant time
get_min_by_third_col() // the method get the minimum triple sort according to the third column, it is also expects the method is running at constant time.
insert_new_elt(triple) // add new trip, running at constant time
```

Is it possbile to implement some data structure like this? I know hashtable could support the first method and heap could support the second and third method, but I do not know how to mix them together. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285168/data-structure-to-store-key-value-pairs-and-retrive-the-key-for-the-lowest-value

Comment: Note that a heap does not support your third method, insert in a heap is O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple data structure that meets your **stated** requirements.

Use a hash table (keyed on the first col) and in addition store a pointer to your minimum element (by the third col). Then, `index_by_first_col` is a hashtable lookup, `get_min_by_third_col` is a pointer dereference, and `insert_new_elt` is a hashtable insert and a comparison to determine if the min pointer needs to be updated.

Note that this gives O(n) deletion (of the minimum), but you didn't state any requirements on deletion.

Comment: actually, I need the delete operation, the more precise description of the 'get_min_by_third_col' should be pop_min_by_third_col